# Multiple audio inputs driven by one MP3 player output

Tags: amplifier, audio

I wish to make the following design using TPA3122D2N as  a DIY project.

[image]

Is it possible I make two or three of these units and share the MP3 players output among all three inputs on the TPA3122 IC?
If not, what sort of modification is required?

Appreciate all responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always good to check the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3122d2.pdf) of a component when you are after information like this. The important thing to know is its input impedance, if that is high, then there is little or no problem connecting a couple of them in parallel. You'll have to develop a feeling for what is high and what is low. Sometimes you even find other useful information about the chip, eg. did you know about "power supply pumping" and how to address that? Interesting topic if you are driving these chips in parallel on the same supply.

Anyways, I admit input impedance is a bit hard to find in the datasheet, it is discussed in the chapter called "Gain setting via GAIN0 and GAIN1 inputs". You may notice some degradation at higher gain settings where the input impedance drops to about 9kΩ. When driving the amps from a headphone output, there should be no issue driving such low impedance. Notice that when driving multiple amplifier in parallel, the MP3 player will see an impedance 9kΩ/N where N is the number of parallel amps.

I'd start to frown when the parallel impedance drops below 1kΩ (9 in parallel) and I'd start to worry when it drops below 100Ω. Most MP3 players are designed to drive 32Ω headphones.

Comment: No offense to forum rules, but I love the answers like these I receive with this extra knowledge. great!

Comment: Could you please recommend me a place to learn about power supply pumping? I think I need it badly.

Comment: @QwertyCoolGuy I didn't know about power supply pumping until I read the chapter about it in the linked datasheet. So I guess Google is your friend, or a question on the stack.

Comment: I did that. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158602/what-is-power-supply-pumping

Answer (score 1):

These chips appear to have a high input impedance, so you should be able to feed one audio source to several inputs in parallel

Comment: so its determined according to input impedance. thanks! Is there a way to determine how many I could connect?

Comment: Page 11 of the datasheet indicates that the input impedance varies with the gain setting, but is at lead 8K ohms.  I think you could easily drive a dozen of these amplifiers from a low impedance headphone output.

Comment: truly appreciate your time @peter! That answers everything!